# Why SQL logical operators do not work in c# command?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, logical-operators

I want to get IDs between Startpoint and EndPoint but I can not Filter query.When I write command without greater then and less then operators it works but searchs all table.

I can't figure out how to fix this. Here's my code; please can you help me?

```
public async Task<int> TaskSearchSqlTweetIDText(string TweetText, string Query, int StartPoint, int EndPoint)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Tools.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select ID from Tweets where @VsTweetText=TweetText and ID<@VsEndPoint and ID>@VsStartPoint", conn);

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VsTweetText", TweetText);

        comm.Parameters.Add("@VsStartPoint", SqlDbType.Int);
        comm.Parameters["@VsStartPoint"].Value = StartPoint;

        comm.Parameters.Add("@VsEndPoint", SqlDbType.Int);
        comm.Parameters["@VsEndPoint"].Value = EndPoint;


        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();

        object sonuc = await comm.ExecuteScalarAsync();
        conn.Close();

        if (sonuc != null)
        {
            return (int)sonuc;

        }
        else
        {
            return 0;

        }
    }
```

Comment: When you try the same query in SSMS, what do you get - how many entries? `select ID from Tweets where @VsTweetText=TweetText and ID<@VsEndPoint and ID>@VsStartPoint`

Comment: Please note (it is also in my answer): Your query also filters for the `TweetText`, so your requirement *I want to get IDs between Startpoint and EndPoint* is incomplete. It should read *I want to get IDs between Startpoint and EndPoint where `TweetText` matches a given value*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state this in your question, so I assume that you're not getting *any* results back from the query as it is?

Probably there are simply no Tweets with IDs strictly greater and strictly smaller than the range you're providing where the `TweetText` matches. You could debug to see what the values for `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` are and if there really is an ID in the database that's strictly between them where the `TweetText` matches.

You could change your statement as follows to include the values for `StartPoint` and `EndPoint`.

```
select ID from Tweets
where @VsTweetText = TweetText
    and ID <= @VsEndPoint
    and ID >= @VsStartPoint
```

or even

```
select ID from Tweets
where @VsTweetText = TweetText
    and ID BETWEEN @VsStartPoint AND @VsEndPoint
```

Please also note that the statement above may very well return more than one record, but you're using `ExecuteScalar` in your code, so you're using the first ID you encounter - randomly. If you're really only interested in *one* ID, you should modify your query so that it is more predictable which one is chosen.

Maybe like this:

```
select top 1 ID from Tweets
where @VsTweetText = TweetText
    and ID BETWEEN @VsStartPoint AND @VsEndPoint
order by ID desc
```

Which would return the biggest ID found within the range.

Comment: Thanks for your interest @Thorsten Dittmar `Select Top 1` solved the problem.

Comment: @Euphoria Strange - it really shouldn't make a difference, as `ExecuteScalar` is defined to return the value of the *first* column of the *first* record (whatever that record is). The `TOP` clause (along with `ORDER BY`) just makes sure the outcome is predictable. **Please note: There should be no `TOP` without `ORDER BY`!**

Answer (score 0):

If you get more than 1 entry from the query in SSMS, you might want to look into the criteria - why is it returning more than one entry. Tighten the `where` clause, make it precise.

```
where @VsTweetText = TweetText
    and ID < @VsEndPoint
    and ID > @VsStartPoint
```

But if you want to get only first entry (if you do), then use this:

```
select top 1 ID from Tweets
where @VsTweetText = TweetText
    and ID < @VsEndPoint
    and ID > @VsStartPoint
```

because you are using `ExecuteScalarAsync` which can return only a single scalar object.